# How to check programmatically to which runtime Google Colab notebook is connected?

Tags: google-colaboratory

In Google Colab is there a way to check programmatically which runtime environment I am connected to: local or hosted?

I want to use this as a conditional in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `sys.modules` like so:

```
import sys
print ('Running in colab:', 'google.colab' in sys.modules)
```